# Gui froze in while loop

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, network-programming, concurrency

server.java

ok, so the problem is: When I hit the start button, the gui "froze", but the server is working, I have an output in console. I think I should use threads for it, but I don't know how to implement it = /

```
void Runer() throws Exception
{
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
    System.out.println("welcome into server");
    while(true)
    {

        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        if (connectionSocket != null)
        {
            System.out.println(connectionSocket);
            Client client = new Client(connectionSocket);
            client.start();
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
class Client extends Thread
{
private Socket connectionSocket;
private String pozX;
private String ans;
private String pozY;
private String capitalizedSentence;
private BufferedReader inFromClient;
private DataOutputStream outToClient;

public Client(Socket c) throws IOException
{
    connectionSocket = c;
}

public void run() 
{
    try
    {    
        inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

        pozX = inFromClient.readLine();
        pozY = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println(pozX);
        System.out.println(pozY);
        capitalizedSentence = pozX.toUpperCase() + '\n';
          BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

       outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Errore: " + e);
    }
}
```

gui.java

```
JPanel GuiServera(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    area = new JTextArea();
    area.setColumns(20);
    area.setRows(10);
    area.setText("The log is logging injoy");
    panel.setLayout(null);
    start = new JButton("Start");
    start.addActionListener(list);
    panel.add(start);
    stop = new JButton("Stop");
    stop.addActionListener(list);
    pane = new JButton("Admin Panel");
    panel.add(stop);

    panel.add(pane);
     scrolled = new JScrollPane(area);
     panel.add(scrolled);
    Insets insets = panel.getInsets();
    Dimension size = start.getPreferredSize();
    start.setBounds(40 + insets.left, 20 + insets.top,
    size.width, size.height);

    size = stop.getPreferredSize();
    stop.setBounds(40 + insets.left, 60 + insets.top,
    size.width, size.height);

    size = pane.getPreferredSize();
    pane.setBounds(40 + insets.left, 100 + insets.top,
    size.width, size.height);

    size = scrolled.getPreferredSize();
    scrolled.setBounds(160 + insets.left, 20 + insets.top,
    size.width, size.height);
    return panel;
}
class Nasluchiwacz implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==start){
            System.out.println("start");
            area.append("start button\n");
            try {
                inzServer.Runer();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
        else if (e.getSource()==stop){
            area.setText(area.getText()+"\nstop\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You've answered it yourself. Your GUI needs to process events to respond to user interaction. You need to run stuff that interferes with the GUI on another thread to prevent that. This isn't hard, just put the code inside a Runnable implementation and then new Thread(runnable).start() it. If your thread needs to interact with the GUI then you need to learn about invokeLater() and invokeAndWait() which queue stuff on Swing's event dispatch thread.

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null);`  Don't do that, learn how to use layouts (+ padding & borders).

Comment: I know how to use layouts, I just find absolute positioning more handy

Comment: @iie: the way to learn about using layouts is to use them. They are truly indispensable.

Comment: 'I know how to use layouts, I just find absolute positioning more handy' - a contradiction in itself ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost doing it correct.
Instead of runner extending thread. Make it implement runnable.

Then in your guiclass. you can either to new Thread(inserver).start(); 
Or take a look at Executorservice or Swingworkers.

Answer (score 0):

you should try using swingWorker.
check this [Tutorial of sun](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)